# Does any function in Pyspark generate the same set of consecutive unique values?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Does any function in Pyspark generate the same set of unique values (like `numpy.arange()`) that can be used as common column between two data frames, which later can be used for joining?

Comment: it depends whether you want to join on a subset of the dataframe or a separate dataframe but i think you can take a look at `row_number` and `monotonically_increasing_id` and use them

Comment: what is the criteria of generating unique values. do you want unique values to be generated for a row using all column value.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the approaches I can think of to generate unique values using all column values of a row-

### Load the test data

```java
String data = " firstname|  lastname|  age\n" +
                " John      | Doe      | 21\n" +
                " John.     | Doe.     | 21\n" +
                " Mary.     | William. | 30";

        List<String> list1 = Arrays.stream(data.split(System.lineSeparator()))
                .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\|"))
                        .map(s1 -> s1.replaceAll("^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$", ""))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read()
                .option("header", true)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .option("sep", ",")
                .csv(spark.createDataset(list1, Encoders.STRING()));

        df2.show(false);
        df2.printSchema();
        /**
         * +---------+--------+---+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|
         * +---------+--------+---+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |
         * +---------+--------+---+
         *
         * root
         *  |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
         *  |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
         *  |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
         */
```

### Create List of all columns present in the dataframe

```java
 List<Column> allCols = Arrays.stream(df2.columns()).map(functions::col).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Approach-1. Calculate [sha2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#sha2) of all columns

> **The Wikipedia page gives an estimate of the likelihood of a collision. If you run the numbers, you'll see that all harddisks ever produced on Earth can't hold enough 1MB files to get a likelihood of a collision of even 0.01% for SHA-256. Basically, you can simply ignore the possibility.**
>   Please note-

1. This approach will create id in `string` format

```java
  df2.withColumn("stringId", sha2(concat_ws(":", toScalaSeq(allCols)), 256))
                .show(false);
        /**
         * run-1
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|stringId                                                        |
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |95903bdd538bc48810c367d0cbe59364e10068fd2511c1a0377015b02157ad30|
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |52092b925014246e67cc80ce460db8791981775f7e2f7a9fc02eed620f7e84f9|
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |a782aa33b3a94148fe450b3e251d0a526ecbe83a4e6fbf49781a2f62dbaadc88|
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         * run-2
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|stringId                                                        |
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |95903bdd538bc48810c367d0cbe59364e10068fd2511c1a0377015b02157ad30|
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |52092b925014246e67cc80ce460db8791981775f7e2f7a9fc02eed620f7e84f9|
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |a782aa33b3a94148fe450b3e251d0a526ecbe83a4e6fbf49781a2f62dbaadc88|
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         * run-3
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|stringId                                                        |
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |95903bdd538bc48810c367d0cbe59364e10068fd2511c1a0377015b02157ad30|
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |52092b925014246e67cc80ce460db8791981775f7e2f7a9fc02eed620f7e84f9|
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |a782aa33b3a94148fe450b3e251d0a526ecbe83a4e6fbf49781a2f62dbaadc88|
         * +---------+--------+---+----------------------------------------------------------------+
         */
```

### Approach-2: Using [row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#row_number) function

> **performance will degrade since there is no partitionBy clause while using big dataset**

Please note-

1. This approach will create id in `number` format

```java
 df2.withColumn("number", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(toScalaSeq(allCols))))
                .show(false);
        /**
         * run-1
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|number|
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |1     |
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |2     |
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |3     |
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         * run-2
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|number|
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |1     |
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |2     |
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |3     |
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         * run-3
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|number|
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |1     |
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |2     |
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |3     |
         * +---------+--------+---+------+
         */
```

### Approach-3: Using `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes`

```java
 UserDefinedFunction id_udf = udf( (String s) ->
                UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(
                        s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                ).toString(), DataTypes.StringType);

        df2.withColumn("stringId", id_udf.apply(concat_ws(":", toScalaSeq(allCols))))
        .show(false);
        /**
         * run-1
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|stringId                            |
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |3d319fa5-7a48-3c21-bdb8-f4546a18dffb|
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |49ab483f-692d-3e14-aa53-2e35e0cf2a17|
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |9b758f70-3723-3623-b262-6d200d6111cf|
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         * run-2
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|stringId                            |
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |3d319fa5-7a48-3c21-bdb8-f4546a18dffb|
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |49ab483f-692d-3e14-aa53-2e35e0cf2a17|
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |9b758f70-3723-3623-b262-6d200d6111cf|
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         * run-3
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         * |firstname|lastname|age|stringId                            |
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         * |John     |Doe     |21 |3d319fa5-7a48-3c21-bdb8-f4546a18dffb|
         * |John.    |Doe.    |21 |49ab483f-692d-3e14-aa53-2e35e0cf2a17|
         * |Mary.    |William.|30 |9b758f70-3723-3623-b262-6d200d6111cf|
         * +---------+--------+---+------------------------------------+
         */
```

Regarding-

> it could be possible that the rows might have duplicates , the duplicate rows should generate different id's and for the subsequent run the id's should be same.

all these approaches will create ids consistently and unique across runs

PS. Please keep below method handy to convert -

```
 <T> Buffer<T> toScalaSeq(List<T> list) {
        return JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(list);
    }
```